# Custom View - self.frame is not correct?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard

So I have a custom UIView class

```
class MessageBox: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createSubViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createSubViews()
    }
    func createSubViews() {

        let testView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        self.addSubview(testView)
    }
}
```

I added a UIView inside the storyboard and gave it some constraints:

> 100 from the top (superview), 0 from the left and right, height is 180

But when I run the app the brown subview I created in the code is way to big. I printed `self.frame` in my custom view and it turns out that the frame is `(0,0,1000,1000)`. But why? I set constraints, it should be something like `(0,0,deviceWith, 180)`.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: That's my Storyboard setup:

[image]

Comment: try to constraint the brownView to its superView with 0 for all four edges!

Comment: Same result. I think it's because the superview's frame is (0,0,1000,1000) though it should not be that

Comment: DId you set the superview constraints properly in IB ? PLease add screenshot of how you set the constrints.

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot

Comment: try to call the method in layoutSubViews method.

Comment: Hm, now the brown view is beneath the white view (that one that I created in the storyboard). But the height and width of the brown value are correct, it's just misplaced. Problem is, I think I can't set constraints here inside the `layoutSubviews()` method (as this is called after they updated constraints, I believe). So I can't reposition it. Even though I have no idea why it is misplaced as the frame of the brown view is the frame of the white view

Comment: I found something that works: `let testView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        testView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)`. The question now is: Why does this only work if I call it inside of `layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: As you see in my comment on the answer below, this still isn't the right way, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Short and simple answer:

You're doing it too early.

---

#### Detailed answer:

When a view is initialized from an Interface Builder file (a xib or a storyboard) its frame is initially set to the frame it has in Interface Builder. You can look at it as a temporary placeholder.

When using Auto Layout the constraints are resolved (= the view's actual frame is computed) inside the view's `layoutSubviews()` method.

Thus, there are two possible solutions for your problem:

1. **(preferrable)** If you use Auto Layout, use it throughout your view.

   - Either add your `testView` in Interface Builder as well and create an outlet for it
   - or create your `testView` in code as you do, then set its `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false` (to sort of "activate Auto Layout") and add the required constraints for it in code.
2. Set your `testView`'s frame after the `MessageBox` view's frame itself has been set by the layout engine. **The only place where you can be sure that the system has resolved the view's frame from the constraints is when `layoutSubviews()` is called.**

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       testView.frame = self.frame
   }
   ```

   (You need to declare your `testView` as a property / global variable, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if we need to pass some data to Custom UIView which needs to used inside layoutSubviews, how can we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the anchors for your view:

```
MessageBox.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active
= true 
MessageBox.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active
= true 
MessageBox.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(150).active = true 
MessageBox.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true
```

This method have to be used inside your class

Answer (score 1):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    testView.frame = self.frame
}
```

this also works when you add a custom class to a UIView in the storyboard and that uses autolayout.
thanks **Mischa** !

Answer (score 0):

try to add a height and width constraint relative to the superview height, with some multiplier.

Comment: tried it, but the problem is that the superview's height and width is 1000. But I don't know why

Comment: probabley because , the layout engine has not finished it’s job yet, so you can’t rely on the frame and bounds size in the method

Comment: The problem is that I can't, for instance, transform the testView as `layoutSubviews()` would reset it immediately after that. I think the problem is that inside the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method the frame hasen't been calculated yet, thus I can't use it. I somehow have to bypass that, I think

Comment: I just posted a similar question regarding that as this could be a bit off-topic here. I will post a complete answer here if I have one. Or maybe someone else has an idea :)