# UIImageView under UIScrollview does not fit on top screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have place UIImageView under UIScrollView on screen with constant width same as screen, and it works fine in iphone 5s but on iphone 7 or 8 the size of image is less than the width of screen size as shared on screenshots.

here is my code:

```
    let x = CGFloat(selectedEvent.album?.count ?? 0)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = (selectedEvent.album?.count ?? 0)

    for index in 0..<(selectedEvent.album?.count ?? 0) {

        frame.origin.x = scroll.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = scroll.frame.size

        print(self.frame.size.width)
        print(scroll.frame.size.width)
        print(frame.size.width)

        let image = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        print(image.frame.size.width)

        if (selectedEvent.album?.count ?? 0) > 0 {
            selectedEvent.getAlbumImage(key: selectedEvent.album![index], completion: { (gotImage:UIImage) in
                image.image = gotImage
            })
        } else {
            image.image = UIImage(named: "defaultImage.jpg")
        }

        scroll .addSubview(image)
    }

    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: scroll.frame.size.width * x, height: scroll.frame.size.height)
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changePage(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

here is the Print Log

```
320.0
320.0
320.0
320.0
320.0
320.0
320.0
320.0
```

[image: Iphone 8][image: story board][image: Iphone 5s Screenshot]

Comment: don't user scrollview width, use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; and calculate frame in ViewWillAppear or in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021503/custom-view-self-frame-is-not-correct

Comment: I was also getting the same issue and tried using `layoutSubviews`, `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`. Didn't work. Then I removed scrollview with `collectionView` having horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I think you need to update the width in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

In shorts, views might not have updated frames on viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear methods instead views are initialised with storyboard sizes. So you are not getting updated rect for iPhone 7 or other devices.
Another reason is scrollview adjusts it's subview automatically. So disable it on viewDidLoad().

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scroll.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never;

    // write your code

  }
```

You should add subviews on viewDidLoad() method as you have done already  and update frame & scrollview content related changes on viewDidLayoutSubviews().

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
    for view:UIView in self.scroll.subviews {
        frame.origin.x = self.scroll.frame.size.width * CGFloat(self.scroll.subviews.index(of: view)!);
        frame.size = scroll.frame.size
        view.frame = frame;
    }

    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: scroll.frame.size.width * selectedEvent.album?.count , height: scroll.frame.size.height)
}
```

Hope will work.

Answer (score 0):

You want the frame width to be the screen width. Use as :

```
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

self.scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: scroll.frame.size.height)
```