# How can I match Custom View's frame with TableViewCell frame properly?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a TableView which contains image stretched into cell and I added a view for darkening the image. Since I want to draw this view only in the beginning and not every time I scroll in table I added my codes into `awakeFromNib` in TableViewCell.

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var equipmentImageView: UIImageView!
let darkFilter = UIView()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    darkFilter.backgroundColor = .black
    darkFilter.layer.opacity = 0.6
    darkFilter.frame = self.equipmentImageView.frame
    equipmentImageView.addSubview(darkFilter)
}
```

My problem is that this view will not have the same width with the ImageView, so the effect I'm trying to implement takes half of the screen.
[image: The dark view only applies half of the screen]

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222046/6213091) solution but the problem is that this solution will only apply after the cells recreate themselves by scrolling down and up again.

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    darkFilter.backgroundColor = .black
    darkFilter.layer.opacity = 0.6
    darkFilter.frame = self.equipmentImageView.frame
    equipmentImageView.addSubview(darkFilter)

}
```

[image: With LayoutSubView function]

How can I apply this solution before the cells are created and will not redraw when scrolling through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the cell's `.background` color to `.black`, and then lower the `alpha` of the `equipmentImageView` and you'd achieve the same darkened effect without having to add a new UIView.

**EDIT**

To illustrate my point: here's a really sloppy and quick example I drew up in Playground with an image titled "Untitled.jpg" to prove fading the image with a black cell background works the same as adding a faded black layer on top of a cell with an image:

Picture of result:

[image: Picture of result]

code:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let myImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        if let sample = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Untitled", ofType: "jpg") {
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sample)
            imageView.image = image
        }

        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return imageView
    }()

    let blackView: UIView = {
        let myView = UIView()
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView.backgroundColor = .black
        return myView
    }()

    let title: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = .black

        let views = [myImageView,
                     blackView,
                     title]

        views.forEach {
            contentView.addSubview($0)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor),
                $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor),
                $0.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
                $0.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
                ])
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setCellViews(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        blackView.alpha = 0

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            if indexPath.row % 4 == 0 {
                blackView.alpha = 0.4
                title.text = "blackLayer added and faded"
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .black
                myImageView.alpha = 0.6
                title.text = "backView faded"
            }
        } else {
            title.text = "not faded at all"
        }
    }
}


private let reuseId = "cellId"

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return tableView
    }()

    let data = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTableView()
    }

    func setTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            tableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            ])
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.setCellViews(indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: @AhmadF why not? Watch this example where a container UIView's background color is set, and then the alpha of an imageView positioned on top of the container view is lowered. The same effect is created: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu9cam3XYiE&t=341s

Comment: Oh got your point, sorry. It could be valid, but do you think it will give the exact same effect as adding a view on top of the image instead?

Comment: Yes, as long as relative alpha’s are proportionate.

Comment: I used @AhmadF 's answer and got it work with an extra, but I appreciate your answer and try it to see it works

Comment: @Egrimo I wonder why my answer got downvote since it worked! Please don't forget to accept an answer :)

Comment: @AhmadF I downvoted it because you're doing extra work when you can just fade the image.

Comment: @Egrimo no problem, but please see my edit. If you add a black UIView on top each time you're doing extra work. (Obviously you don't have to write out all the programmatic views like I did, I just did that because I did it in Playground)

Comment: @WilsonDesimini could you please mention this on any answer you are aiming to downvote?! because its really annoying to get a downvote without an explanation. Furthermore, I think it is not a good idea to downvote it since it works, even if you think that has "extra work" it is still works. Honestly, sometimes I find it really funny and sad from the community to get a downvote for a valid answer from someone you are upvoting his answer :)

Comment: @AhmadF if you edit it (like not change it but just add a word in or something to "edit" it) I'll remove the downvote (I can't remove it otherwise since my vote is locked given I voted 12 minutes ago).

Comment: I applied both of your methods. I don't think that neither of them should be downvoted since the question is open. If the user wants the darken affect, WilsonDesimini 's answer is much better approach since you don't create any extra elements. However if you need to add extra view to show something else on image, @AhmadF 's answer is the good solution for that. No need to downvote anyone.

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

1) Since you are dealing with `IBOutlets` for the cell, you could also add the view on the IB on top of the image view, and then adding constrains to it to match up the image view size.

2) If you are aiming to adding it programmatically, you might need to setup its constraints based on the cell content view. For example:

```
darkFilter.backgroundColor = .black
darkFilter.layer.opacity = 0.6

contentView.addSubview(darkFilter)
darkFilter.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
darkFilter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
darkFilter.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
darkFilter.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
darkFilter.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```